# How to align icon and dropdown side by side?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to align the image and dropdown side by side. While it works perfectly for icon and text when I try to put dropdown on the right side of the icon, it goes a little below than the icon, ie they are not aligned perfectly next to each other.

```
 <View style = {{flexDirection:"row"}}>
      <Image
     style={{alignSelf:'baseline'}}
          source={require('/root/VS_Code/JavascriptProjects/App/assets/Images/Religion/Religion.png')}
        />

       <Dropdown
inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent',width:130 }}
        label='Marital status'
        data={dataForMaritalStatus}

      />

</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `justifyContent:"center"` in parent View

```
<View style = {{flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:"center"}}>
   <Image style={{alignSelf:'baseline'}}
   source={require('/root/VS_Code/JavascriptProjects/App/assets/Images/Religion/Religion.png')}/>

   <Dropdown
    inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent',width:130 }}
    label='Marital status'
    data={dataForMaritalStatus}

  />
```